# SQL Server 2005 Replication, transactional with updateable subscription error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication

Several days ago i setup some replication for our SQL Server 2005 database, the type of replication was a transactional with updateable subscription.

The replication are working fine, lately i test the upgradeable subscription feature by modifying 1 data on subscriber server but then the error was raise and data are not committed.

The error was:

```
Error Source: .Net SQLClient Data Provider.
Error Message: The RPC security information for Publisher is missing or invalid. Use sp_link_publication to specify it.
Updateable subscription: Rolling back transaction.
....
```

I have check both publisher and subscriber username and password, and since i use mixed authentication and i have set the same username & password for publisher and subscriber it can't be wrong.

My replication schema was like this:
[Replication schema http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms151196.89217927-03fc-4ba0-8110-73ada9810b3f(en-us,SQL.100).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms151196.89217927-03fc-4ba0-8110-73ada9810b3f(en-us,SQL.100).gif)

(the left image which use 3 server), lets say A was publisher and B/C was subscriber

Anyone have a solution for this problem? I prefer a more GUI solution rather than T-SQL if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved, the issues was in fact deals with MS DTC, i've modified MSDTC setting and recreate the replication (both publisher and subscriber) and now it's work

PS:
- MSDTC can be accessed on Administrative Tools -> Component Services -> Right click on Computer and go to MSDTC tab
- Right there i check all items and press Apply then recreate the replication

Answer (score 0):

Sorry no GUI solution, I would run

`sp_link_publication.`

This link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174991.aspx

Explains the parameters

Hope that helps

Comment: any harm when i misuse this stored procedure?

Comment: It's already broken right - Make sure your parameters are correct